# Compilation Error in i/o redirection in C program in linux

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm trying to make a simple I/O redirection(ls to sort)(ls|sort>f1) and then my next step is to direct the output of sort to a file in C but when compiling gcc is giving following error..plz help me :)

Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
int a,b,c,d,pfd[2],kk,i,j;
FILE *fp;

i=fork();
if(i==0)
{
    pipe(pfd);
    j=fork();
    if(j==0)
    {
        close(1);
        dup(pfd[1]);
        close(pfd[0]);
        close(pfd[1]);
        excel("/bin/ls","/ls",0);
    }
    else
    {
        close(0);
        dup(pfd[0]);
        close(pfd[0]);
        close(pfd[1]);
        /*close(1);
        kk=open(f.txt,O_WRONLY);
        dup(kk);
        */
        excel("/usr/bin/sort","/sort",0);
    }
}
else
    wait();
/*char k[100],pp[100],ll[]="/bin/";
printf("Enter the cmd to execut");
scanf("%s",k);
strcpy(pp,k);
strcat(ll,k);
printf("%s",ll);
system(ll);*/
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

> */tmp/cc6wIvoJ.o:*
>
> ```
> In function **main**:
> j.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to **excel**
>
> j.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to **excel**
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Comment: Error: /tmp/cc6wIvoJ.o: In function main': j.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference toexcel'

j.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `excel'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

There are some bogus answers here which I can't comment on since I don't have '50 reputation' points. Hence an entirely new reply instead.

As correctly noted by people you obviously have a typo, you want *execl* instead of *excel*.

However, people claim that execl is a system call. IT IS NOT. It's a convenience function in your libc. Syscall which is executed at the end of the day is execve, which you can confirm by e.g. using strace.

There are several issues with your code, do you have warnings enabled when you compile? -Wall -Wextra to gcc will definitely help out.

Example issues:
- wait() *takes an argument*, and you would be warned about this if only you had proper header files included
- missing error checking (fork, pipe, wait)

In general your coding style will lead you to trouble.

Always include relevant headers (to be found in manpages) and check return values.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a system call called `excel`. Hence you are getting undefined error. Try using one of the `exec()` family of calls like execl. -

> http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl

Answer (score 0):

Its execl not excel . execl is the call you are looking for.